# Binding by relative source is not working in Tooltip WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am using Syncfusion visual style. I am trying to bind the ToolTip foreground inside the TextBlock present inside the StackPanel for displaying the ToolTip text.But the binding doesn't work properly in the TextBlock.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
   <CheckBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding AutoAdd, Mode=TwoWay}">
      <CheckBox.ToolTip>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,5">Automatically Add To Path</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}">
               If this path is associated with the primary configuration,
               <LineBreak />
               automatically add newly instantiated optical elements to the end of the path.
            </TextBlock>
            <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Margin="0,8" />
            <WrapPanel>
               <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" />
               <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}" FontStyle="Italic">Press F1 for more help</TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
         </StackPanel>
      </CheckBox.ToolTip>
   </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

Any other work around regarding this issue.

Regards,
Hari Prasad

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How do you set the `ToolTip.Foreground`? If it's set in tooltip style, then textblocks will inherit its value. Just remove those bindings.

Answer (score 1):

A Tooltip is in a different datacontext and not directly in the visual tree to a control which appears to be it's parent.  Hence, when you search up the visual tree using relativesouce, it will find nothing.

You may use PlacementTarget to reference the thing which is nominally it's parent - checkbox in your markup

```
   "{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Here PropertyName is whichever property you want.

That could be DataContext.ViewModelProperty if you wanted a property in your viewmodel.

In this instance I would try

```
Foreground="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Depending on your usage, maybe using a dynamicresource would be simpler though.